# Casting and Reflection C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, reflection

I am trying to cast an Object to its type using reflection.

So I want to do something like use the typeOf() method to find its type and then dynamically cast the object to its found type.

I am not sure how to do this nicely maybe using linq?

I am using c# 4.0.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Your requirements don't make much sense. The runtime type is left unchanged by most casts, and the compiletime type is irrelevant in a dynamic context.

Comment: And what are you gonna do with the casted object?

Comment: Your premise appears invalid, as this would only be useful if you already knew the type prior to compile time.  In this case, I'd just do an "as" cast and check for null.  On the other hand, if you need to convert from `IEnumerable<object>` to `IEnumerable<SomeType>` look into the `OfType<T>()` extension method.

Answer (score 7):

The object already has its type. Its being stored in a variable of type object only means that you (the programmer) do not know the type at programming time or that you do not want or are not able to specify it. You can only cast to a type which is known at design (programming) type. I do not know what you are intending to do, but probably casting to dynamic will achieve what you desire:

```
dynamic dyn = obj;
```